# javascript in asp.net masterpage doesn't load

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My litte alert function in JScript1.js doesn't work anymore 
It did work, but I can not get it to work again !!! 
I did clean, and rebuild, reboot pc etc. 
My pc Windows 10, Microsoft Edge, VS 2010 
How Can I get it working again ?
If A copy the code in a new project it is working, see bottom, in which case it's holding wrong information?
*Oh I found a solution !*

**My Site.Master:**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebJavascriptTest.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE etc etc...">
<head runat="server">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="JScript1.js"></script>
```

**My About.aspx**

```
-<%@ Page Title="About Us" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebJavascriptTest.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Javascript in file
    </h2>
    <asp:Button ID="B1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="notify()" /
```

**My JScript1.js**

```
function notify() {
    alert('notify test');
}
```

**My working WebJava.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebJava.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebJavascriptTest.WebJava" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function Func() {
        alert("hello!")
    }
</script>
    <h2>
        Java Intern
    </h2>
    <asp:Button ID="B1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="Func()" />
```

**To Make a same test project**
Add new project
ASP.NET Web application
Add new item JaScript file name JScript1.js
Put code in JScript1.js

```
function notify() {
    alert('notify test');
}
```

Add in Site.Master under link-stylesheet next line:

```
   <script language="javascript"  type="text/javascript" src="JScript1.js"></script>
```

Add next line in About.aspx under about:

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="notify()" /><br />
```

Now you have a working example
But at some moment it doesn't work anymore, how is that possible?

**Solution:**
After VS load and show the webpage, click on reload, I my case it's working !?!

Comment: Can you check one thing, instead of `OnClientClick="notify()" `, write alert statement and check whether it will call or not?

Comment: Oh I suspect that, it called that function, but it will postback that page immediately as button is clicked. So just simply add return false, to cancel button's click event, like `OnClientClick="notify(); return false"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that the JScript1.js file is stored in the browser cache. Every time you run the application, the cached version of the file is used instead of the current version. For example, if you change the code for:

```
function notify() {
    alert('Notify 2');
}
```

and run your application again, you will not see this new message unless you clear your browser cache (or if the browser is set to clear it automatically).

You can force the browser to load the new Javascript file by appending a different query string to the file name each time the application starts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JScript1.js?<%# DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() %>"></script>
```

In real world applications, it is preferable to force the browser to download JScript1.js only when its content has been modified. This can be done by appending the file version to the file name (instead of a time tick count). The script declaration line could look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JScript1.js?version=<%# AppVersion %>"></script>
```

which would use an AppVersion property defined in code-behind:

```
public string AppVersion
{
    get
    {
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
    }
}
```

The version of the assembly file should then be updated (in the properties of the project) when a change is made in JScript1.js.